# Displaying multiple tables using a cells values as criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I will have Multiple Tabs, each tab will be called

Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta etc

Every tab will have contain multiple tables containing values, called...

{TABNAME}First, {TABNAME}Second, {TABNAME}Third, {TABNAME}Forth.
this will ultimately give me 4 tables for First called,

AlphaFirst, BetaFirst,GammaFirst, DeltaFirst.....

I was wondering if there is anyway i can pick/input a value in a cell, on a tab with none of these tables, for instance select 'Third'
And below this cell, or anywhere on this tab all version of 'third' will appear, so the tables for AlphaThird, BetaThird, GammaThird etc will appear, either seperatley, or the data merged into a single table.

if you need more information or examples, please let me know and i will update as best i can.

I guess to summarise, is it possible to call forward multiple tables using a cell as the criteria for which tables to call forward.

**Further details - Edit**

Every table will contain the same column headers and contain the same ranges of data within them. They will always have the same number of columns, However each table can contain any amount of rows.
The values in the tables are all manually typed or picked from a pickList, containing no Formula

To put this into a Scenario, there is 5 shops, a Tab for each, On each Tab is a Table for each Supplier we have, containing any Order information from that store for each supplier.
I wish to choose a supplier on a separate tab and have all orders with that supplier appear on the page for every store. the Store name does not need to be displayed, i just wish to know what is on order with that supplier.

Comment: Yes every table will have the same column headers and contain the same ranges of data with them, they will all remain the same size (in columns) but may change in Row length per sheet. The Table content is all text/numbers, with no formula, most of it is picked from a drop down.

Comment: I guess one way to describe the scenario is a tab for each 'shop' and each table is a supplier with a delivery on order, so on my main sheet i will want to pick a supplier, and it will grab all tables relevant to that supplier from each Shop sheet and display all orders currently with them

Comment: The Text does not have to be merged, as long as when 'cell a1 = supplier' multiple tables below populate with information from each tab, that would suffice! I will have a play with Pivot tables and see what i can figure out